# How convert MySQL Date with php

Tags: php, mysql, date

`<?php echo $row_noticia_datos['fecha']; ?>` results in

> 2013-11-16

But, I expect to get following:

> 2013-November-16

or best

> 16 - November - 2013

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Here's all you need: http://php.net/strtotime and http://php.net/date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = (new DateTime($row_noticia_datos['fecha']))->format('d - F - Y');
```

or

```
$date = date('d - F - Y', strtotime($row_noticia_datos['fecha']));
```

You can also do this in your SQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d - %M - %Y') AS fecha
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtotime` and do

```
<?php echo date('j - F - Y', strtotime($row_noticia_datos['fecha'])); ?>
```

This will output `16 - November - 2013`